# Page behaves differently in Facebook Sharer/ Status than in Facebook Debugger/Linter

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've been working on the og tags for our bilingual website; which uses a jquery slider to change languages (as well as changing the pages title on the fly) from English to Arabic.

All english pages are thus www.ourwebsite.com/page/**#en** (or just www.ourwebsite.com/page/, as English is the default) and all arabic pages are www.ourwebsite.com/page/**#ar**

The problem is that when i use the facebook linter, both the above pages give me the same response (which is the desired and correct one), but when i simply share them in facebook, the #ar pages give me what seems like the 1st paragraph of the arabic content as the page title (it also grabs the arabic description, which is an unintended but welcome quirk). What i want is for the #ar page to either behave exactly as the english page does when pasted in facebook sharer or just have the arabic description but the english/arabic title remain the same.

Here are the facebook debugger results for a sample page in each language:

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fanstonesaudiarabia.com%2Fpartners%2Flist%2F%23en
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fanstonesaudiarabia.com%2Fpartners%2Flist%2F%23ar

As you see, they are identitical. However, pasting the second URL into facebook's status gives a much different link preview title (basically its all the arabic page text content).

Any help is appreciated,

-Shadi

Comment: Just noticed the following: The (wrong) title is the arabic text + the correct title; its appended at the end of the string. So basically, some text scraped from the page content is set up as the title, then the og:title is added to its end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you don't have the og:url tag in both the pages. Can you try and add the og:url meta tag and have that point to the base url without the #en or #ar tag ? That will inform the facebook scraper to extract meta content from that url.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; i will try to do that and see what comes out of it :)

Comment: It fixes the issue (somewhat). However, it means those sharing the #ar page won't get all-arabic info (and doesn't explain what was happening). Also, when i used the linter; i get: **Circular redirect path detected:**. Original: **http://anstonesaudiarabia.com/partners/you/#ar  
og:url: http://www.anstonesaudi.com/partners/you  
301: http://www.anstonesaudi.com/partners/you/  
og:url: http://www.anstonesaudi.com/partners/you** 
It doesnt seem to be affecting the sharer though, so I'm pleased with it as a workaround. Thank you!

Comment: of course, the above behavior is the same when using anstonesaudi.com instead of anstonesaudiarabia.com (first thing that i thought might be producing the 301).